# Can we add a three.js plugin for questions?

Tags: feature-request

After using Atlassian's Confluence, I have gotten dependent on their [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/) plugin that allows me to quickly draw up a diagram to illustrate my thoughts. For 3D questions/answers, the [Three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) would be a nice tool to have to quickly demonstrate a simplified 3D scene. Since the Three.js editor is a Javascript plugin, it seems like we could utilize that here on Blender SE.

Devs, is this a feasible feature?

Users, would you use a simple, browser-based 3D editor to illustrate ideas in your questions or answers?

Comment: To be honest I think I personally would end up firing up blender every time instead.. Maybe that's just me though.

Answer (score 2):

I can not speak to how easy to would be to implement, as I am not a dev.

However, as a user I can say that that no I would not use it.
This is a site about blender, and in most questions some feature of blender is at heart. So I go not see the benefit of adding an in browser 3D editor, that cannot come close to all the features blender has, and are asked about.

Even if I was to make a simple scene to demo something, I would just make it in blender (often times blend files are a plus).